# Ansible URI module: override hostname to reach backend web servers using virtual hosts

Tags: ansible, uri, virtualhost

We have a few loadbalanced webservers which are configured to use virtual hosts to host multiple websites.
Because of the virtual hosts, we need to send the correct domain name to the web server when establishing a connection to any website.

We want Ansible to directly access the individual backend webservers (with the uri module).

Similar to how we can override the host with the `--connect-to` parameter in curl:
``` curl --connect-to serverhostname:443 ``https://www.example.com ```

Now I've figured we can use the url field to directly connect to the backend server, and pass the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) website as a http host header. But I can't find how to override the SNI extension for HTTPS websites.

Or alternatively to make Ansible use the correct URL, but override the IP/hostname for the connection itself (similar to how curl does it)

```
- name: Wait for the webserver to return a 200

  uri:

    url: "https://serverhostname:443/"

    method: GET

    status_code: 200

    return_content: no

    headers:

      host: "www.example.com"

  register: result

  until: result.status == 200

  retries: 10

  delay: 1
```

I've also tried using the Ansible proxy function, to connect to the backend server. While keeping the uri's URL parameter correct. But this results in "error tunnel connection failed".

Background info/goal: We want to test our redundant backend webservers individually, and make sure they still respond properly, before a playbook continues to make changes on the other servers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do it is using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to create a unix socket forwarding to the target URL, and then using that with the `unix_socket` option to `ansible.builtin.uri`:

```
---

- name: Example URI request with alternate hostname using socat
  hosts: all
  vars:
    target_url: https://127.0.0.1/balancer-manager
    target_hostname: www.example.com

- name: Set variables for socat connection
  when: target_hostname is defined and (target_url | urlsplit('hostname')) != target_hostname
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    socat_unix_socket: "/var/tmp/{{ target_hostname }}"
    socat_target_address: >-
      {% if target_url | urlsplit('scheme') == 'https' %}
      OPENSSL:{{ target_url | urlsplit('hostname') }}:{{ target_url | urlsplit('port') | default(443, true) }},commonname={{ target_hostname }}
      {% else %}
      TCP:{{ target_url | urlsplit('hostname') }}:{{ target_url | urlsplit('port') | default(80, true) }}
      {% endif %}
    modified_url: "http://{{ target_hostname }}{{ target_url | urlsplit('path') }}?{{ target_url | urlsplit('query') }}"

- name: Start socat and run URI task(s)
  block:

    - name: Start socat asynchronously
      when: socat_unix_socket is defined
      ansible.builtin.command: >
        socat
        UNIX-LISTEN:{{ socat_unix_socket }},fork,accept-timeout=10
        {{ socat_target_address }}
      changed_when: false
      register: socat_result
      async: 300
      poll: 0

    - name: Access target URL via unix socket
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: "{{ modified_url | default(target_url) }}"
        unix_socket: "{{ socat_unix_socket | default(omit) }}"

  always:

    - name: Wait for socat to finish (timeout)
      when: socat_unix_socket is defined
      ansible.builtin.async_status:
        jid: "{{ socat_result.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: socat_job_result
      until: socat_job_result.finished
      retries: 60
      delay: 5
```